# How to access const inside another function in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a file called `home.js` that looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, Text, FlatList, Card, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'

export const addProject = (flowerbed) => {
flowerbed.key = Math.random().toString()
setFlowerbed((currentFlowerbeds) => {
return [flowerbed, ...currentFlowerbeds]
})
setModalOpen(false)
}

export default function HomeScreen() {

const [flowerbeds, setFlowerbed] = useState(false);   

return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <FlatList data={flowerbeds} renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity >
      <Card>
        <Text>{ item.title }</Text>
      </Card>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )} />
  </View>
)
}
```

In function `addProject` I need to call function `setFlowerbed` which is inside `HomeScreen`, but I get an error: *can't find variable: setFlowerbed*. I cannot put function `addProject` inside `HomeScreen` because I need to access it in another file:

```
import { addProject } from './screens/home';
```

Is there a way to fix this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps put `const [flowerbeds, setFlowerbed] = useState(false);` before `export const addProject = (flowerbed) => {`

Comment: Error: invalid hook call

Comment: Can you move the modal component inside `Homescreen` and have it control the state? That way you can also move the function inside the component.

Comment: `addProject` doesn't have access to `setFlowerbed` which is why it doesn't work. Please share the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass the callback function to use the function wich you choose, the same with the modal

```
export const addProject = (flowerbed, flowerbedCallback, modalCallback) => {
  flowerbed.key = Math.random().toString()
  flowerbedCallback((currentFlowerbeds) => {
    return [flowerbed, ...currentFlowerbeds]
  })
  modalCallback(false)
}
/** You need to invoce the method like this, 
two parameters: setFlowerbed & setModalOpen, are functions but are not called
so you will can execute inside addProject function */
addProject(flowerbedExample, setFlowerbed, setModalOpen);
```

If you pass the function as parameter, when you call it, are you passing the method to his scope, vecause you are passaing the reference of the function, so when you executre the parameter *callback* you will execute the reference